# Vagrant accessing public mysql server

Tags: mysql, vagrant

I have a Vagrant VM running on a local machine. But unable to connect to an external public mysql server. I'm able to ping the mysql server, but unable to connect.

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on '***.net' (110)
```

Comment: Make sure the credentials and config are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The problem was that the mysql server was listening to 127.0.0.1 only

Comment: can you share your config?